# Get average time difference between current and previous row

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by, aggregate-functions

I would like to get the average difference (in seconds for example) between two distinct rows using an aggregate function with group by.

Lets say I've a table like this:

```
id   | ts                  | data
1123 | 2022-01-19 07:15:23 | ...
1124 | 2022-01-19 07:17:28 | ...
1125 | 2022-01-19 07:21:19 | ...
1126 | 2022-01-19 07:21:23 | ...
.
.
.
1227 | 2022-01-19 09:01:04 | ...
```

At first I want to group this and want to have a count how many rows we have per day. This is easy:

```
SELECT DATE(ts), COUNT(data)
FROM table
GROUP BY DATE(ts)
```

and the result looks like this:

```
DATE(ts)   | COUNT(data)
2022-01-18 | 519
2022-01-19 | 104
```

But additional to this I would like to have the average distance (in seconds) between the previous row so that I get an idea of how frequently new data is inserted. So the result should look like this:

```
DATE(ts)   | Average Difference | COUNT(data)
2022-01-18 | 12                 | 519
2022-01-19 | 14                 | 104
```

Is there a way to get such an information using SQL?

Comment: It would be much easier for me to understand if your desired outcome was based on your sample data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using MySQL 8 or later you can use `lag` function to find the previous datetime in order to calculate the difference. Rest is straight forward:

```
with cte as (
    select cast(ts as date) as dt
         , ts
         , lag(ts) over(partition by cast(ts as date) order by ts) as prev_ts
    from t
)
select dt
     , count(*) as count
     , avg(timestampdiff(second, prev_ts, ts)) as avg_diff
from cte
group by dt
```

Comment: You could use [DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function rather than casting the date

Comment: Fantastic! This is exactly what I need! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You may approximate the average distance in minutes between all records on a given date by just taking the difference between the latest and earliest timestamp, divided by the count:

```sql
SELECT DATE(ts),
       TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, MIN(ts), MAX(ts)) / (COUNT(data) - 1) AS avg_distance,
       COUNT(data)
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY DATE(ts);
```

Comment: `COUNT()` must be decremented. There is N-1 gaps between N values. Of course for alone value the average gap will be NULL/undefined.

Comment: @Akina It might make sense to just use `AVG` in this case, which avoids the divide by zero problem altogether.

Comment: For SELECT, division by zero returns NULL. Hence no problem.

Comment: MIN/MAX inside AVG won't fly.